# MPDF simple header and footer not working

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I am using mpdf for making simple pdf files, but there is a problem with my footer and header. Here is my code

```
$ppdf = new mPDF('UTF-8','A4',0,'sans serif'); 

$ppdf->debug = true;
$ppdf->useOnlyCoreFonts = true;
$ppdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$ppdf->SetAutoFont(0);

$stylesheet = file_get_contents('templates.css');

$css = "<style>".$stylesheet."</style>";

$ppdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);

$ppdf->WriteHTML($css);
$ppdf->WriteHTML($conent);

$ppdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);

$protokolFile = "downloads/MEDpredavaci-protokol-".date('d-m-y').".pdf";
$ppdf->Output($protokolFile, 'F');
```

Footer create only once on the last page and header does not create at all.

I have this css

```
@page {
     margin: 200px 20px 200px 20px;
    }
```

Because some of you suggest me to make space from top and bottom of every page. So where is the problem? Can you help me please?

header code:

```
$header = "<table>
  <tr>
     <td>Header</td>
  </tr>
</table>"
```

footer code:

```
$footer = "<table>
  <tr>
     <td>Footer</td>
  </tr>
</table>"
```

Comment: in my case, the mpdf header and footer were not showing no matter what I did, and what solved my problem was to add `$mpdf->AddPage()` right after `$mpdf = new ....`

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like [(from MPDF documentation)](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=313)  :

$mpdf->DefHTMLHeaderByName('Chapter2Header','Chapter 2');

$mpdf->DefHTMLFooterByName('Chapter2Footer','Chapter 2 Footer');